# Change Android Studio keybind for Code > Split > Design

Tags: android-studio, keymapping

I am using Android Studio 4.1.1 on Windows, and I would like to use the key combinations "Alt+Shift+Left" and "Alt+Shift+Right", but those are bound by default to switching the editor's view mode between "Code", "Split" and "Design", and I cannot see them in the keymap settings, i.e. I cannot find how to remove them. I can set the two keybinds in the keymap settings, but they will be ignored and the view mode will switch instead.

I've always used those keybinds for another purpose, and would rather avoid having to use a different keybind set on Android Studio than I have on Visual Studio Code.

For your curiosity, my regular usage:

*To move the cursor within a word such as camelCaseWord*

- ctrl+right to go from current position to the end of word
- alt+right to go from current position to the next word boundary, in this case next capital letter(e.g. from m to C)
- alt+shift+right to select from current position to next word boundary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find these keybindings in Keymap > Other > Tabs :

1. Select Next Tab in multi-editor file  > Alt+Shift+Right
2. Select Previous Tab in multi-editor file > Alt+Shift+Left

**After removing these key bindings, you probably will need to restart  your Android Studio instance for the changes to take effect.**

Comment: It seems like I had removed them and applied the changes, but maybe a restart was necessary for it to be taken into account. Thanks !